# ASP.net razor :: how-to send a contact form and don't refresh the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using ASP.net Razor c# for making my web and I need to avoid refreshing all the page, because I'm using only one Layout for making all the web and if I make a POST-back when I submit the form I'll get the Default page.

I have it working with an iframe, it works well. But I want to make something like the Pagemethods(one friend told me... he knows more...).

Maybe it's the same as ASP.net but, I have only 3 days experience in web development and I have a mess in the head with all this acronyms. Thanks!

This is my Contact form, I call it with an iFrame now:

```
@{  
 var result = "";


 if(IsPost){           

        if(Request["mail"].IsEmpty())
        {          
            ModelState.AddError("correo", "*error insert mail");
        }           

        }else{
        var message = "<p>Your message:</p>";           
        message += "Mensaje: " + Request["mensaje"] + "<br />";           
        WebMail.Send(
                to: Request["mail"],
                subject: "New message",
                body: message,
                isBodyHtml: true
                );
        result = "Done";
    }
    }else{
        //In action I call the iframe                
    <form id="contacto" action="@Href("~/Contacto1")" method="post">                    
   .
   .
   .

    </form>  
    }
    }
```

Comment: You have way too much logic in your View.

Comment: Sorry... now the problem is abstracted.

Comment: I didn't say that to sound harsh, but you will quickly spiral out of web control with having so much business logic code in your Views.  You typically keep business logic in Models.

Comment: I will keep this on mind on the future. Thanks.

Comment: So... I'm a little bit confused. Do I need to add server code apart from what I'm writting in the .cshtml? Or can I do the same with Razor sintax?

Comment: It's considered best practice to have minimal code on the view. In this example, in keeping with that best practice, much of the code above would be moved to the controller. There is also debate as to what is appropriate for a controller and what is better suited for the "model", but that's another discussion.

Comment: I worked on a project that was my company's first MVC project, meaning they made all their mistakes on it, and I had the pleasure of maintaining it. There were some big ol' views where if case #1, render this huge blob of html, else render another similar but sightly different blob of html, and some of those views had hundreds of lines of code. I was able to maintain it, but it wasn't fun nor easy, needlessly complicated. I'm not vehemently against having some view-side code, but it's just a good rule of thumb to check your view before you wreck your view, knowhatimean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Bob The Janitor says, you must get yourself familiar with the jQuery methods $.post and $.ajax and so forth. They sure do let you create a seamless experience. Link to the jQuery docs on ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

your going at it a little wrong, try doing it with jQuery.

Post the form in ajax and render the view returned, here is a blog post that kind of show how to do it http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2011/11/more-ajax-with-mvc-using-partial-views.html, I'm working on one that deal specifically with posting forms over ajax and using model based validation on the returned view